# Jquery help -menu

Tags: jquery, css, html, menu

im trying to get it so that when you click the search bar icon the menu slowly disappears but something ins't right with the code and it isn't toggling it. Its stuck as hidden.

*ok update I fixed the code, however the effect to toggle the animation once clicking the search icon isnt working. Here is the new code*
**Script Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search').click(function () {
        $('.menu-item').toggleclass("hide-item")
    })
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.menu ul li a.menu-item
{
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: 0.5s;
    display: block;
}

.menu ul li a.menu-item.hide-item
{
    transform: scale(0);
}
```

Comment: You have syntax error this line  $('.menu-item')addclass("hide-item")
use  $('.menu-item').addclass("hide-item")

Comment: Hey! I tried doing that as well it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try this selector: .menu ul li .menu-item.hide-item instead of .menu ul li .menu-item, hide-item

Comment: I updated the code to a somewhat working one, but i still have one issue, I edited my question

Comment: You need to share your HTML code as well

Comment: it is working fine as expected - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/EJBWxV , please provide HTML to debug and find issue